Cart is not cleared after purchase because of wc_update_product_stock() function
I have this a this action to fired when an order changes status to "processsing".
This code causes a problem: the cart is no cleared after a purchase.
I found that the line which is causing this issue is: wc_update_product_stock( $product,  $product_stock , 'set' );
But I don't how to fix it. Is there another way to update the product stock? Why is this happening?
Important: only happens with orders which get the "processing" status right away in the purchase.
This issue doesn't happen if the order is set to "on-hold" and then I edit the order and change the status manually to "processing".
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status){ 
   if($new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'on-hold'){
     
    // in previous lines I fetch the $product_sku

    $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $product_sku );
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product_stock = 100000;
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
    wc_update_product_stock( $product,  $product_stock , 'set' ); // THIS LINE CAUSES THE ISSUE



    }// close if($new_status == 'processing'){
} 


@LoicTheAztec I agree with you but in my tests the issue is gone as soon as I remove this line of code. I am 100% sure. You are right, I tried to force the 'empty cart' from other ways, but none of them worked.

I believe you… I may have an alternative that could solve the issue, see it on my answer below.

Any feedback on my alternative? Did you try it?

You could try to use instead the WC_Abstract_Product setter methods set_manage_stock(), set_stock_quantity() and set_stock_status() in your code like:
## Previous lines code to fetch the $product_sku

// Fetch the product SKU
$product_sku = '';  // Replace with your method to fetch SKU
$product_id  = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $product_sku );
$product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product_stock = 100000;

    $product->set_manage_stock( $true );
    $product->set_stock_quantity( $product_stock );
    $product->set_stock_status( 'instock' );
    $product->save();
}

It could solve your issue.
